# Julia: convert 1x1 array from inner product to number

Tags: julia

What is the best way to get a number out of an inner product operation, rather than a 1x1 array. Is there a better way than this:

```
([1 2 3]*[4 5 6]')[1]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If possible, I wouldn't do the inner product manually, I'd use `dot`, i.e.

```
 dot([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
```

I've noticed that you don't actually have vectors there though, instead you have `1x3` matrices (rows), so if thats really what you have you'd have to `vec` them first, which is a bit unpleasant:

```
dot(vec([1 2 3]), vec([4 5 6]))
```

Alternatively, one could do

```
 sum([1 2 3].*[4 5 6])
```

which doesn't care about the dimensions.