# How should I convert a singleton Array to a scalar?

Tags: arrays, julia, scalar

Let's say I have an `Array` variable called `p`:

```
julia> p = [5]
julia> typeof(p)
Array{Int64,1}
```

How should I convert it to scalar? `p` may also be 2-dimensional:

```
julia> p = [1]'' 
julia> typeof(p)
Array{Int64,2}
```

(Note: the double transpose trick to increase dimentionality [might not work in future versions of Julia](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/4774))

Through appropriate manipulation, I can make `p` of any dimension, but how should I reduce it to a scalar?

---

One viable approach is `p=p[1]`, but that will not throw any error if `p` has more than one element in `p`; so, that's no good to me. 
I could build my own function (with checking),

```
function scalar(x)
    assert(length(x) == 1)
    x[1]
end
```

but it seems like it must be reinventing the wheel.

What does not work is `squeeze`, which simply peels off dimensions until `p` is a zero-dimensional array.

(Related to [Julia: convert 1x1 array from inner product to number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28845323/julia-convert-1x1-array-to-number/28845582#28845582) but, in this case, operation-agnostic.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [`only`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/iterators/#Base.Iterators.only), which was introduced in Julia v1.4

```
julia> only([])
ERROR: ArgumentError: Collection is empty, must contain exactly 1 element
Stacktrace:
  [1] only(x::Vector{Any})
    @ Base.Iterators ./iterators.jl:1323
  [...]

julia> only([1])
1

julia> only([1 for i in 1:1, j in 1:1, k in 1:1]) # multidimensional ok
1
```

Answer (score 10):

If you want to get the scalar but throw an error if the array is the wrong shape, you could `reshape`:

```
julia> p1 = [4]; p2 = [5]''; p0 = []; p3 = [6,7];

julia> reshape(p1, 1)[1]
4

julia> reshape(p2, 1)[1]
5

julia> reshape(p0, 1)[1]
ERROR: DimensionMismatch("new dimensions (1,) must be consistent with array size 0")
 in reshape at array.jl:122
 in reshape at abstractarray.jl:183

julia> reshape(p3, 1)[1]
ERROR: DimensionMismatch("new dimensions (1,) must be consistent with array size 2")
 in reshape at array.jl:122
 in reshape at abstractarray.jl:183
```